# Какой тип будет видеть cout при выводе. Символьные строки

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, char, символы

При записи `const char *str = "Hello";` и выводе `cout << &str[1] << endl;` какой тип будет видеть cout? char * ? Но почему именно в такой тип преобразовывается? Тот же вопрос и при записи `char str1[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };` и том же выводе. Почему &str[1] обрабатывается именно с типом char * . И почему тогда при записи `const char *str3[] = { "Hello", "World", "Test" };` и выводе `cout << &str3[1] << endl;` cout будет видеть тип char** ?? Вопрос именно по c++.

Comment: Если `str[1]` имеет тип `const char`, то тогда `&str[1]` имеет тип `const char *`...

Comment: Если `str3[1]` имеет тип `const char *`, то тогда `&str3[1]` имеет тип `const char **`... В чём суть проблемы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const char *str = "Hello";
```

`&str[1]` - это адрес первого элемента, т.е. символа `e`. Тип `str[1]` -
`const char`, тип `&str[1]` - `const char *`, обрабатывается при выводе как строка.

```
char str2[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

Тип `str2` - `char[6]`, выражениt `str2[1]` имеет тип `char`, ну, а  тип `&str2[1]` - `char *`, обрабатывается при выводе как строка.

```
const char *str3[] = { "Hello", "World", "Test" };
```

Массив **указателей**. Тип `str3` - `const char *[3]`. Тип `str3[1]` - тип элемента массива, т.е. `const char *`. Массив состоит из трех элементов-указателей, так что `&str3[1]` - получение **адреса** второго элемента массива. Понятно, что его тип - после взятия адреса - `const char * *` - одна звездочка от типа элемента, вторая - от взятия адреса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128825/discussion-on-answer-by-mikhailo-----cout---).